# Can I make cakes in a tagine?

Tags: baking, biscuits, cakes

I am living in Marrakech and in our new place I don't have an oven, and don't really want to buy anything expensive as we will only be here for a few months.

I would like to make cakes/biscuits (and possibly bread), but is this going to be possible without an oven?  I have a tagine, could I re-purpose that to make some sort of cake or biscuit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to recall that in Moroccan cities there are often 'neighbourhood' ovens where you pay a small amount to have your bread baked, because few people have their own ovens.

You cut a distinctive design in the loaf so you can tell which is yours when you go back to collect it; the whole system is extremely ancient. The ovens are usually wood-fired clay ovens, so you'll get a nice stone-baked result as well.

Comment: Thanks, after a bit of asking around, it appears that we have a communal oven at the end of our street, which fires up everyday before lunch time.  Whoopee!  thanks, I wouldn't even have considered this before!

Comment: Welcome - not a bad answer considering I've never been anywhere in Africa before, let alone Morocco! The wonders of TV... :D

Answer (score 5):

I would think you'd be able to.  I'd look for recipes on camping websites for baked goods in dutch ovens, as it'd be pretty similar.

You should be able to pull off biscuits and brown bread pretty easily.  And I'd tell you about [cakes cooked on campfires](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4626/cakes-that-can-be-cooked-whilst-camping) such as upside-down cakes, but you're the one who asked about it earlier.

Comment: Dutch oven recipes are an excellent idea as they will account for the higher humidity level in the Tagine than normal cake done in an oven.